# Recursive Cleaning

Tags: c++, parsing, pointers, recursion, memory

So I developing recursive descent parser and didn't finish it, because I have a problem with pointers. To be honest - it's not a problem, I simply want to ask whether I'm doing the right thing. So you can see this code:

```
class Expression
{
public:
    virtual int eval() = 0;
    virtual ~Expression() {}
};

class BinExpression : public Expression
{
private:
    Expression * expr;
public:
    BinExpression() {}
    BinExpression(Expression* in): expr(in) {}

    int eval()
    {
        return 1;
    }

    ~BinExpression()
    {
        if(expr) delete expr;
    }
};

class FxExpression : public Expression
{
private:
    Expression * expr;
public:
    FxExpression() {}
    FxExpression(Expression* in) : expr(in) {}

    int eval()
    {
        return 2;
    }

    ~FxExpression()
    {
        if (expr) delete expr;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Expression* expr;
    expr = new BinExpression();
    expr = new FxExpression(expr);
    delete expr;
    return 0;
}
```

---

**Certainly**, I deleting **ALL** my pointers to classes and I **haven't** memory leaks!

---

The essence of this approach is that I can make enclosed Expression and this allows me to solve the simplest mathematical operations taking into account the priority of signs.
As you can see, programm deleting pointer (FxExpression) at the end and in the destructor class deleting class inside him (BinExpression). I can put more Expression using this way and they will be deleted recursively **without** memory leaks! (I tested it with hundred classes)

So, finally, my question - can I use this "imbedded" method for real projects or this way looks like junior trash-code?

Comment: *"Certainly, I deleting ALL my pointers to classes and I haven't memory leaks!"* - Just an unhealthy dose of passing an uninitialized pointer to `delete`.

Comment: "_To be honest - it's not a problem, I simply want to ask whether I'm doing the right thing._" [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is a place better suited to ask for code reviews.

Comment: You know, you don't really get to *tell* people how to react to your question... if you suspect it is a badly written question, maybe improve it instead of expecting readers to put in the extra work? As to the style, you may want to read about the [**Rule of Five** and **Rule of Zero**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) - a class should *either* own a single resource, *or* provide some functionality, but not both. There are good Standard Library resource-owning utilities you might use, such as [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr).

Comment: It is also perfectly safe to `delete` a `nullptr` (pointer with value `0`), but **not** an uninitialised pointer, so perhaps set `expr` to `nullptr` in the default constructor.

Answer (score 0):

One problem with deleting children nodes in the destructor is that when the tree is sufficiently deep it is going to run out of stack space recursing down the tree. A solution is to have all nodes stored in arrays elsewhere with nodes not owning other nodes. This way destroying the tree does not cause recursion.

Please note that `delete` and `std::free` handle `null` pointers, no need for that extra check.

Comment: Thanks for feedback! In fact, I ask whether this is a good example or there are ways to make the parser different. At the expense of a deep tree - yes, I tested this: enough thousands of nested nodes and a pointer error is issued